# Synchrosqueezed STFT phase transform

Tags: stft, time-frequency, cwt, synchrosqueezing

Synchrosqueezed STFT paper, [Synchrosqueezing based Recovery of Instantaneous Frequency from Nonuniform Samples](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.2533), defines STFT phase transform as:

$$
w(u, \xi) = \xi - \frac{\partial_tS_{g}f(u, \xi)}{j2\pi S_gf(u, \xi)}
$$

Which differs from synchrosqueezing original paper's - A Nonlinear Squeezing of the [Continuous Wavelet Transform Based on Auditory Nerve Models](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Eingrid/publications/DM96.pdf) (per CWT) two-fold:

1. The $\xi\ - W$, where original's is simply $W$
2. The $2\pi$, absent in original's

Why the differences; what motivates STFT's definition? And why use 'modified' STFT?

Comment: well, i have, on one or two occasions, asked and answered a question myself.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson [So have others](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/239063), and they're well-received.

Comment: It is great to have people asking and answering their own questions. Usually this means the answer is deep and the information is valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**:

1. CWT's $\partial_t$ is taken with respect to *wavelet timeshifts*, STFT's with respect to *window time samples*, with CWT's FT taken along *rows*, and STFT's along *columns*.
2. The $2\pi$ is per assuming a different 'oscillatory factor' of Fourier Transform's kernel, i.e. $e^{-j2\pi f}$ vs. $e^{-j\omega}$. Numeric implementations can work with either.
3. "Why modified STFT" is a separate question, addressed in second answer.

---

#### Motivating phase transform

To derive CWT's phase transform, original paper uses $f(t) = A \cos(\Omega t)$ as a motivating example, or for our purposes equivalently $A e^{j\Omega t}$, then works backwards from the result of $\partial_t W_f / W_f$ to define $w$ such that $\Omega$ is extracted. The idea is, this $f(t)$ is the *basis function* (building block, atomic unit) of the Fourier Transform, so results here will transfer to  any other $h(t)$ the more $h(t)$'s (D)FT is "well-behaved" (more specifically, $h(t)$'s "components" obey synchrosqueezing assumptions detailed in [followup paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.2437)), which spans a large variety of real-world signals.

---

#### Deriving phase transform

The SSQ STFT paper considers $e^{j\omega t}$ directly, but omits a derivation; I will derive it here for both the 'standard' and 'modified' STFT, along their derivatives, from which the phase transform will arise naturally.

Let $f(t) = e^{j\xi_0 t}$, and assume a real, even-symmetric ($g=g^*,\ \hat{g} = \hat{g^*}$), window $g(t)$. We have:

$$
\begin{align}
S_gf(u, \xi) 
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) g(t-u) e^{-j\xi t} dt \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{j\xi_0t} g(t-u) e^{-j\xi t} dt \\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2\pi \delta(\omega -(\xi - \xi_0)) \hat{g}(\omega) e^{-ju\omega} d\omega \\
& = \hat{g}(\xi - \xi_0) e^{-ju(\xi - \xi_0)} \\
\end{align}
$$

where [Plancherel-Parseval's Theorem](https://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ejdg/eeft3.pdf) was applied, and similarly

$$
\begin{align}
S^{\text{mod}}_g f(u, \xi) 
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) g(t-u) e^{-j\xi (t-u)} dt \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{j\xi_0t} g(t-u) e^{-j\xi (t-u)} dt \\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2\pi \delta(\omega -(\xi - \xi_0)) \hat{g}(\omega) e^{-ju(\omega - \xi)}d\omega \\
& = \hat{g}(\xi - \xi_0) e^{ju\xi_0} \\
\end{align}
$$

The derivatives are:

$$
\begin{align}
S_{g'} f(u, \xi) 
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) g'(t-u) e^{-j\xi t} dt \\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2\pi \delta(\omega -(\xi - \xi_0)) j\omega\hat{g}(\omega) e^{-ju\omega} d\omega \\
& = j(\xi - \xi_0)\hat{g}(\xi - \xi_0) e^{-ju(\xi - \xi_0)} \\
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
S_{g'}^{\text{mod}} f(u, \xi) 
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) g'(t-u) e^{-j\xi (t-u)} dt \\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2\pi \delta(\omega -(\xi - \xi_0)) j\omega\hat{g}(\omega) e^{-ju(\omega - \xi)}d\omega \\
& = j(\xi - \xi_0)\hat{g}(\xi - \xi_0) e^{ju\xi_0} \\
\end{align}
$$

Then, for both cases, to retrieve $\xi_0$, we consider the ratio

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial/\partial t( S_{g}f(u, \xi) )}{S_gf(u, \xi)} = \frac{S_{g'}f(u, \xi)}{S_gf(u, \xi)} = j(\xi - \xi_0)
\end{align}
$$

which leads us to define

$$
\begin{align}
& \boxed{ w(u, \xi) = \xi - \frac{S_{g'}f(u, \xi)}{jS_gf(u, \xi)} } \\
&= \xi - \frac{j(\xi - \xi_0)}{j} = \xi_0 \\
\end{align}
$$

Note the phase transform being same for both is one consequence of the division "reducing influence of windowing".

---

#### Verifying derivation

$S_g f(u, \xi)$ expression can be verified with an example, comparing against [Wolfram's output](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier+transform+e%5E%28i*x%29+*+e%5E%28-pi*%28x+-+u%29**2%29) (set normalization=1, oscillatory factor=-1):

$$
\text{Let}\ f(t) = e^{jt},\ g(t) = e^{-\pi t^2}, \text{ and thus}\ \hat{g}(\xi) = e^{-\xi^2 / (4\pi)}.\ \text{Then}, \\
$$
$$
\begin{align}
S_gf(u, \xi) 
&= \hat{g}(\xi - 1) e^{-ju(\xi - 1)} \\
&= \exp{\left( -\frac{1}{4\pi}(\xi - 1)^2 - ju(\xi - 1) \right)} \\
&= \exp{\left(\frac{1}{4\pi}( (\xi - 1)(-j4\pi u - \xi + 1 )\right)} \\
\end{align}
$$

More completely, ssqueezepy's [`ssq_stft`](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/blob/master/ssqueezepy/_ssq_stft.py) on a variety of signals yields expected behavior.

---

#### Why the $2\pi$?

The TL;DR pretty much says it, which can be verified in the original MATLAB Toolbox's [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.0010). In code, with frequency-domain differentiation, the $2\pi$ makes it so we define $j \omega$ to span $[0, ..., \pi]$ and $(-\pi, ..., 0)$, and without uses $0.5$ instead of $\pi$, reinterpreting the derivative's dimensionality as linear cyclic fraction of sampling frequency, rather than radian. See [code](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/blob/0.5.5/ssqueezepy/_stft.py#L232).

---

#### Why the $\xi\ -$?

CWT's $\partial W_f$ takes $\partial / \partial b (\psi((t-b)/a))$, where $b = $ timeshift, whereas STFT's takes $\partial / \partial t (g(t))$. This is per how each is computed:

1. CWT takes DFT along *rows*; for every scale (row), we use frequency-domain convolution to correlate the wavelet with the signal at every timeshift $b$ (column).
2. STFT takes DFT along *columns*; for every timeshift (column), we apply DFT to correlate the windowed signal with cisoid bases at every frequency (row).

Following the derivations from motivating examples reveals the $\xi \ -$ stemming from this difference.

The definitions can be interchanged or made the same for both; why exactly they differ I'm unsure. My bet is, CWT is best computed for every timeshift (`hop_length = 1`), and the scales are already sparse, whereas in STFT we often apply large `hop_length` (small overlap), so convolution theorem is very compute-wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why 'modified' STFT?

Authors merely state it's "convenient for our purposes", which isn't much. My exploring reveals: extreme numeric instability in reassignment and component inversion of 'standard'. In fact, most STFT implementations *do not* compute the 'standard' (clarified around $(2)$):

$$
S_f[u, k] = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f[n] g[n - u] e^{-j 2\pi k n / N}  \tag{1}
$$

#### Default STFT is extremely unstable along columns

The default (i.e. as implemented by most libraries) STFT is extremely sensitive to imperfections or mere finite-ness in the phase transform: for a given column, values in rows plot into wavelet-like oscillations, meaning upon summation (ssqueezing), exclusion of even a single value greatly impacts the final value in a given `Tx` location. This seems to be a major (but unstated) motivation for ssqueezing according to the Lebesgue measure, rather than invertible summation.

I've verified this with a perfectly set up pure sinusoid (no shadow frequencies); perhaps the remedy is in also using a perfect window, but this many perfections are hardly realistic (or generalizable). Since Lebesgue sets all values in `Sx` to `1`, exclusion of any one value is no big deal, and we see a dramatic improvement:

[image]

`lebesgue`'s main strength is also its main weakness: values away from ridge (STFT max row) are (as should be) much smaller, but are counted as equals, which exacerbates noise energy and general perturbations. A simple compromise, then, is to sum `abs(Sx)` - which seems to work ideally:

[image]

Problem is, we may lose invertibility, but not necessarily by a lot (e.g. Griffin-Lim).

#### Example: superimposed inverted exponential chirp

[image]

"Modulated" (modified) sums well both directly and via `abs()`, while default creates a mess. Key is the last plots, showing `Sx` values for a single column. This is the direction we synchrosqueeze, or sum, along; summing directly, we alternate between locally close peaks of opposite signs, keeping the sum total small. Adding or removing just one peak can amount to doubling the net-sum *and* flipping its sign.

To contrary, modulated is a lot smoother; no big deal if a few samples get misassigned. How's it work? For once, the answer's in `fft(fft(x))`; aside unimportant differences, DFT of DFT of `x` is `x`, and `x` is the windowed signal:

[image]

A *centered* window thus corresponds to `fft(x)` that has high-frequency oscillations, whereas a window 'centered' about `n = 0` (wrapping around) bears low frequencies, thus the smooth plot.

#### 'Standard' STFT is also modulated

DFT is taken always with window centering a data segment, meaning the window is fixed relative to the DFT complex sinusoids (cisoids), or the cisoids move together with the window when they should remain zero-phased at t=0 (Eq. $(1)$).

Difference is, this "modified" variant has a much more favorable shift factor, and is in exact agreement with its claimed mathematical formulation:

$$
S^{\text{mod}}_f[u, k] 
= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f[n] g[n - u] e^{-j 2\pi k (n - u) / N}  \tag{2}
$$